# "Undefined Reference..." when compiling FFT (Using FFTW3 library)

Tags: compiler-errors, fftw

So, I'm trying to cross-compile to ARM using edited FFTW for arm from vesperix.com (version 3.2.2)

But, When I am trying to compile my code with this command in line

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o fft fftw_example.c -L/usr/local/lib/lfftw3.a -lm
```

This error appear

```
/tmp/ccFFFtbv.o: In function `main':
fftw_example.c:(.text+0x34c): undefined reference to `fftw_plan_dft_1d'
fftw_example.c:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to `fftw_execute'
fftw_example.c:(.text+0x380): undefined reference to `fftw_destroy_plan'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do anyone know why ? And how to fix it?

This is my code for ARM fftw, I use someone's code from internet.

```
/* Start reading here */

#include <fftw3.h>

#define NUM_POINTS 64


/* Never mind this bit */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1

void acquire_from_somewhere(fftwf_complex* signal) {
    /* Generate two sine waves of different frequencies and
     * amplitudes.
     */

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; ++i) {
        double theta = (double)i / (double)NUM_POINTS * M_PI;

        signal[i][REAL] = 1.0 * cos(10.0 * theta) +
                          0.5 * cos(25.0 * theta)  ;

        signal[i][IMAG] = 1.0 * sin(10.0 * theta) +
                          0.5 * sin(25.0 * theta);
    }
}

void do_something_with(fftwf_complex* result) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; ++i) {
        double mag = sqrt(result[i][REAL] * result[i][REAL] +
                          result[i][IMAG] * result[i][IMAG]);

        printf("%g\n", mag);
    }
}


/* Resume reading here */

int main() {
    fftwf_complex signal[NUM_POINTS];
    fftwf_complex result[NUM_POINTS];

    fftwf_plan plan = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(NUM_POINTS,
                                      signal,
                                      result,
                                      FFTW_FORWARD,
                                      FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    acquire_from_somewhere(signal);
    fftwf_execute(plan);
    do_something_with(result);

    fftwf_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftwf_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the fftw.h file in your code?

Comment: this problem has solved. But now I got new problem when trying to execute the fft, I got segmentation fault.

Comment: Make sure the size of your FFT when planning is the same size as the input and output vectors. If you pass size `n` to `fftw_plan_dft_1d` then both input and output vectors must be size `n`.

Comment: I have posted my full code. I did the right thing just like what you answered and Still got the same error, segmentation fault. I have no idea. Can you try to cross-compile my code by using `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`. This is my command to compile the code `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a9 fftwku.c -lm -lfftw3f -o fft3`

Comment: I see you've changed every instance of `fftw_` to `fftwf_` (which is correct since you're compiling the float version of fftw). However you said you are getting the same error which displays the regular `fftw_` functions. Is this still happening?

Comment: Yes, I saw on the website of fftw.org that I have to change every instance of `fftw_` to `fftwf_` for single precise (arm) . In addition to executing the *.exe program in linux, I do `chmod +x *.exe`. I still dont get it why this is still happening

Comment: I added a lil change to my code, since I am enabling precision, I have to change `double` data type to `float`. Unfortunately, the error still remains the same `segmentation fault`. Sad.

Comment: Please find out where the segmentation fault happens. I have a suspicion it's happening when you run `acquire_from_somewhere` or `fftwf_plan_dft_1d`.

Comment: How to trace the segmentation fault? I have no idea to do that.

Comment: Do some print statements in between instructions.